# Higlight a desired "n-th" author in \fullcites in cleanthesis?

Tags: biblatex, highlighting

I have found different answers about highlighting authors in biblatex in the bibliography but not so much in specific citations.

I have different `\fullcite{Label}` commands along a text where I show the full reference of some papers from different authors. I use the [clean thesis](http://cleanthesis.der-ric.de/) template

> I would like to highlight a different author in each fullcite
>   (bold, underline, colorized, whatever). For instance, lets say to make
>   bold the 1st author in the first fullcite but the 3rd author in
>   another fullcite and so on.

However, the bibliography has to remain the same. No highlights there.

> Is there any way to highlight the n-th author in a fullcite as
>   `\fullcite{LabelA}[1]` or `\fullcite{LabelB}[3]` or some command for that?

Thanks for any help you could provide.

Comment: You have tagged your question with BibTeX and you also explicitly mention it in your question, but the `\fullcite` makes me think you are really using `biblatex`. Can you check that? In any way, a solution will not only depend on the package you use, but also on the bibliography/citation style. The easiest way to make sure that we have all the info we need is by providing a complete, compilable example document, an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407). Please add one to your question, so we can be sure we talk about the same thing.

Comment: Also: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Thanks a lot moewe. I use the clean thesis template (http://cleanthesis.der-ric.de/ ) . Both bibsystems are mentioned in the style file but not sure which one is the right one here.  I included the following line to order the refs by appearance:  PassOptionsToPackage{sorting=none}{biblatex}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in [Biblatex style authoring. How do we refactor DeclareCiteCommand to taken an additional parameter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/340548/35864) there is no official way to add another argument to `\cite` commands and I feel that abusing the pre- or postnote argument is not good style here. So I used the naive approach where you call a macro `\highlightnames` and give the names to be highlighted there. The list of highlighted names is stored between `\fullcite`s and can be emptied with `\resetnamehighlights`, the starred version `\highlightnames*` resets the list before adding new numbers.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\resetnamehighlights}{\let\nhcbx@highlightlist\@empty}
\resetnamehighlights

\newcommand*{\highlightnames}{%
  \@ifstar{\resetnamehighlights\highlightnames@add}{\highlightnames@add}}

\newcommand*{\highlightnames@add@inner}[2]{%
  \listeadd{#1}{\the\numexpr#2\relax}}

\newcommand*{\highlightnames@add}{%
  \forcsvlist{\highlightnames@add@inner\nhcbx@highlightlist}}

\newcommand*{\mkbibhighlightnthname}[1]{%
  \xifinlist{\the\value{listcount}}{\nhcbx@highlightlist}
    {\mkbibbold{#1}}
    {#1}}
\makeatother

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{highlightnthname}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibcompletename}{\mkbibhighlightnthname}%
  #1}


\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{author}{highlightnthname}%
      \DeclareNameWrapperAlias{editor}{highlightnthname}%
      \DeclareNameWrapperAlias{translator}{highlightnthname}%
      \DeclareNameWrapperAlias{sortname}{highlightnthname}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
\highlightnames{1}
{\frenchspacing\fullcite{sigfridsson}}

\highlightnames*{2}
{\frenchspacing\fullcite{sigfridsson}}

\resetnamehighlights
{\frenchspacing\fullcite{sigfridsson}}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: "Sigfridsson and Ryde" in various combination of bold-ness. The first citation has "Sigfridsson" highlighted, the second "Ryde", the third none of the two. The bibliography has no names highlighted either.]

*edit* Modified to work with `biblatex` v3.13 and above. For older versions see the edit history.

Comment: Awesome Moewe! Thanks a lot. It even works if you want to highlight more than one author.