# Chaining \StrBefore and \mkcomprange

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

I would like to split the output of `\mkcomprange` using `\StrBefore` (or vice-versa, or something else equivalent), but neither ordering seems to work.

1. Desired output: `23-24;34-35` becomes 23–24.
2. Output of `\mkcomprange{\StrBefore{23-24;34-35}{;}}` is 23-24.
3. Output of `\StrBefore{\mkcomprange{23-24;34-35}{,}}` is blank.

I'm guessing the output of #3 is because `\mkcomprange` doesn't output a literal comma, but I can't figure out why #2 doesn't work, whereas `\mkcomprange{23-24}` outputs 23–24 as expected. I should note that this is all in the context of `biblatex-chicago`.

---

For broader context: I'm working on a custom biblatex entry type that requires that I parse two distinct sets of page numbers out of the postnote and print them in two distinct places in the citation. The first set is the cited document's own internal paragraph numbering, whereas the second is the pages of the particular printed edition being used. For example, I would like `\autocite[23-24;34-35]{doc}` to output 'Author, Document Title 23–24: Book Title (Place: Publisher, 2020) 34–35'. I have all the other pieces in place, but I haven't been able to figure out how to get the two different numbering schemes to work.

My current setup looks roughly like this:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote:first}{%
    \mkcomprange{\StrBefore{#1}{;}}%
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote:second}{...}
\printfield[postnote:first]{postnote}
\printfield[postnote:second]{postnote}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), in which the packages providing commands `\mkcomparerange` and `\StrBefore` are loaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an expandability issue paired with the fact that string manipulation is hard in TeX.

Essentially `biblatex`'s `\mkcomprange{<text>}` only works as advertised if its argument `<text>` is a literal string. If the argument is too complex to be parsed correctly by `\mkcomprange`, `\mkcomprange` will simply do nothing. Not even

```
\newcommand\foo{23-24;34-35}
\mkcomprange{\foo}
```

works as one might hope, since `\foo` is not a string (it is a macro expanding to a string).

In

```
\mkcomprange{\StrBefore{23-24;34-35}{;}}
```

`\mkcomprange` does nothing, because its argument is too complex and only `\StrBefore` does its thing, leaving us with

> ```
> 23-24
> ```

and not the desired

> ```
> 23\bibrangedash 4
> ```

---

Coming back to the `\foo` example from above, the following works

```
\newcommand\foo{23-24;34-35}
\expandafter\mkcomprange\expandafter{\foo}
```

because the `\expandafter`s make sure to expand `\foo` first before `\mkcomprange` sees it, so that `\mkcomprange` is not called with the argument `\foo` (which doesn't do the right thing, see above) but with `23-24;34-35` (which works).

Thinking further along those lines, one might try

```
\expandafter\mkcomprange\expandafter{\StrBefore{23-24;34-35}{;}}
```

Unfortunately, that fails spectacularly with all kinds of error messages. The problem here is that the command `\StrBefore` is not expandable, which means that it can not be massaged with commands like `\expandafter` (or in an `\edef` context) to just reveal the string directly.

The developer of `xstring` implemented a way of working around that: You can let `\StrBefore` write its output to a macro and use that. So the following again works

```
\StrBefore{23-24;34-35}{;}[\AVBtemp]
\expandafter\mkcomprange\expandafter{\AVBtemp}
```

---

For your simple requirements, you don't need `xtstring` at all. You can build something that splits your postnote at the `;` yourself.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\AVBpostnotesplitcompOne}[1]{\AVBpostnotesplitcompOne@i #1;\relax}
\def\AVBpostnotesplitcompOne@i#1;#2\relax{%
 \ifblank{#2}
   {\mkcomprange{#1}}
   {\AVBpostnotesplitcompOne@ii #1;#2\relax}}
\def\AVBpostnotesplitcompOne@ii#1;#2;\relax{\mkcomprange{#1}}

\newcommand*{\AVBpostnotesplitcompTwo}[1]{\AVBpostnotesplitcompTwo@i #1;\relax}
\def\AVBpostnotesplitcompTwo@i#1;#2\relax{%
 \ifblank{#2}
   {}
   {\AVBpostnotesplitcompTwo@ii #1;#2\relax}}
\def\AVBpostnotesplitcompTwo@ii#1;#2;\relax{\mkcomprange{#2}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\AVBpostnotesplitcompOne{Hallo}|\AVBpostnotesplitcompTwo{Hallo}

\AVBpostnotesplitcompOne{23-24;35-36}|\AVBpostnotesplitcompTwo{23-24;35-36}

\AVBpostnotesplitcompOne{23-24;}|\AVBpostnotesplitcompTwo{23-24;}

\AVBpostnotesplitcompOne{;35-36}|\AVBpostnotesplitcompTwo{;35-36}

\AVBpostnotesplitcompOne{23-24;35-36;46-45}|\AVBpostnotesplitcompTwo{23-24;35-36;46-45}

\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Hallo|//23–4|35–6//23–4|//|35–6//23–4|35–6, 46–5]

---

```
\StrBefore{\mkcomprange{23-24;34-35}}{,}
```

doesn't work because because `\mkcomprange` is not expandable and so `\StrBefore` performs its actions on `\mkcomprange{23-24;34-35}`, where there is no comma to be found.

---

You may also be interested in [Optional argument within another optional argument in biblatex \cite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95110/35864), where Audrey shows a way to split the argument structure of the postnote into different subarguments.

Comment: The `\expandafter` solution works fine for my needs (I'm happy to keep `xstring` in favour of more readable code), but thank you for the alternatives as well. Thank you also for the explanation; I'll keep that in mind while debugging in the future.

Comment: As it turns out, the solution without `xstring` is more stable. Some of the citations include § (so something like `§14;17-18`), and the `xstring` solution choked on that.

Comment: moewe, may I (ab)use this for a ping on a related issue? (I tried the chat first, but no completion of your handle there...) Do you happen to know why `maxcomprange` exists? What is the reason to impose an upper limit beyond which compression no longer occurs?

Comment: @gusbrs Sorry, absolutely no idea. Maybe for symmetry reasons? Maybe someone requested it.

Comment: @moewe It got me curious, I'm looking into implementing similar functionality for page cross-references and, naturally, `biblatex` was the first place I looked. And I could not find a reason for it to exist, thus the question. Thanks for answering!