# Why does “displayquote” break when citing with an optional argument and how to fix it?

Tags: biblatex, biber, csquotes

If you use the optional argument of “displayquote” from “csquotes” it breaks the “displayquote” environment's optional argument, where you are supposed to put in a cite text.
This is really not a thing that should break, given i do exactly what I'm supposed to do.

Here a full example:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = de_DE
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,oneside]{scrbook}
\KOMAoption{listof}{totocnumbered, leveldown}

% deutsch
\usepackage[english, german, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[english, german, ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage{lmodern} % font
\usepackage[autostyle, german=quotes]{csquotes} % deutsche Anführungszeichen mit \enquote

% Referenzen
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,
sortcites=true,
sorting=none,
defernumbers=true,
%maxcitenames=3,
minbibnames=3, % cite up to three authors in bib
backref=true,
backend=biber]{biblatex}
%\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind} % fügt Referenzen zu TOC hinzu
\usepackage{nameref}

% test bib
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{dsgvo-eu-2016-679,
    author={{Europäisches Parlament} and {Europäischer Rat}},
    title = {Verordnung (EU) 2016/679 des Europäischen Parlaments und des Rates vom 27. April 2016 zum Schutz natürlicher Personen bei der Verarbeitung personenbezogener Daten, zum freien Datenverkehr und zur Aufhebung der Richtlinie 95/46/EG (Datenschutz-Grundverordnung) (Text von Bedeutung für den EWR)},
    date={2016-04-27},
    note = {Deutsche Fassung},
    journal = {Amtsblatt der Europäischen Union},
    url = {https://data.europa.eu/eli/reg/2016/679/oj}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Zitat:
\begin{displayquote}[\cite[Erwägungsgrund 6]{dsgvo-eu-2016-679}]
Das Ausmaß der Erhebung und des Austauschs personenbezogener Daten hat eindrucksvoll
zugenommen. Die Technik macht es möglich, dass private Unternehmen und Behörden im Rahmen ihrer
Tätigkeiten in einem noch nie dagewesenen Umfang auf personenbezogene Daten zurückgreifen. Zunehmend
machen auch natürliche Personen Informationen öffentlich weltweit zugänglich. Die Technik hat das
wirtschaftliche und gesellschaftliche Leben verändert und dürfte den Verkehr personenbezogener Daten innerhalb der Union sowie die Datenübermittlung an Drittländer und internationale Organisationen noch weiter erleichtern, wobei ein hohes Datenschutzniveau zu gewährleisten ist.
\end{displayquote}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

LuaLaTex then throws me a lot of strange error like “Runaway argument?” or “Emergency stop. […] (job aborted, no legal \end found)”.

If you omit the optional argument in the cite and cite `\cite{dsgvo-eu-2016-679}` instead of `\cite[Erwägungsgrund 6]{dsgvo-eu-2016-679}`, it works flawlessly.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78414/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99495/35864

Answer (score 1):

Oh actually [also thanks to this related answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95205/98645) I've found the solution:
You need to put the inside in `{}` brackets.

So e.g. `[{\textcite[Erwägungsgrund 6]{dsgvo-eu-2016-679}}]` works.
(Note I also switched to `\textcite` to avoid double brackets in the `numeric` citation style.)